# Javascript generated elements always overlapping on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to build a quiz following this tutorial : https://www.sitepoint.com/simple-javascript-quiz/
I didn't touch much to the logic and added bootstrap integration (+ meta viewport tag). FYI, I tried without theses changes and my issue is still there.

The quiz is quite straight-forward but I'm struggling making it work on mobile devices. The problem is that I'm not sure to understand the real origin of the issue and therefore, I have a hard time describing it precisely.

In that tutorial, the question and its answers are generated by javascript while the navigation/submit buttons below them aren't, meaning that I have to set a minimum height for the container in which the questions/answers will be generated. Without that, the buttons are displayed prior to the js-generated code and the buttons will be display on top of the question/answers container. Quite logical :

```
<div class="quiz-container">
    <div id="quiz">JS generated Questions and Anwsers go here</div>
</div>            
<button id="previous">&lt;&lt;</button>                                     
<button id="next">&gt;&gt;</button>                                    
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>   
<span id="results"></span>
```

It works fine on desktop but not so much on mobile : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lxz7p.png
The answers and questions are overlapping making the quiz unusable, especially since I'm adding the good answers on submit to their radio element, generating even more overlapping.

I tried to set another min-height on mobile in CSS, I tried using the "vh" units, I tried playing around with margin/padding but no matter what I do, it will always look like that on mobile. Actually, changing margins or padding around the buttons area will have an effect on the desktop view but none on mobile. The elements will always overlap the same way.

I'm fairly sure it's some logic in the structure of the page on mobile that I don't understand but I really can't put my finger on it despite my many researches and attempts.

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, use percents and vw for measuring units.
Secondly, use box-sizing property in css and set it to border-box. 
And the last, read more about @media [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp). This piece of code is very important :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```